# how to use echo download link if checkbox is selected

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

i have a check box where user can choose which PDF they want to download. user can choose more than one PDF..once submit ..user will get an email with the download link. i managed to email the user but unable to provide the download link based on what they choose from the checkbox.any help would be much appreciated

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('/config/database.php') ;
error_reporting(0);

//if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(isset($_POST) && ($_POST['submit'] == 1)){




$error = '';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$Country = $_POST['Country'];
$checkBox = implode('<br>', $_POST['download']);
$registered_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

//foreach($_POST['download']  as  $value)  {
//$check_msg .= "Checked: $value\n";
} 

if ($_POST['secCode'] != $_SESSION['securityCode']) {
    //  unset($_SESSION['securityCode']);
         $error .= "<script>alert('Sorry the security code is invalid. Please try it     again')</script>";
    }



   if ($error == ''){

    foreach($_POST AS $key => $value) { $_POST[$key] =  mysql_real_escape_string($value); }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, country,download, registered_at)
            VALUES           ('$name','$email', '$Country', '" . $checkBox . "', '$registered_at' )";  
    if (mysql_query($sql)){

    //email function start


//html checkbox
<div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                        <p><h5>Select device to download (&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' name='checkall' onclick='checkedAll(subscribe);'><label>&nbsp&nbsp;Select all</label>) </h5></p>
                        <!--DIAGNOSTIC DEVICES-->
                          <input id="1" class="placeholder span4_1" type="checkbox" name="download[]" value="1"><label>1</label><br>
                          <input id="2" class="placeholder span4_1" type="checkbox" name="download[]" value="2"><label>2</label><br>
                          <input id="3"  class="placeholder span4_1" type="checkbox" name="download[]" value="3"><label>3</label> <br>     
                          <input id="4" class="placeholder span4_1" type="checkbox" name="download[]" value="4"><label>4</label><br>
                          <input id="5" class="placeholder span4_1" type="checkbox" name="download[]" value="5"><label>5</label><br>
                          <input id="6" class="placeholder span4_1" type="checkbox" name="download[]" value="6"><label>6</label> <br>
                          <!--THERAPEUTIC DEVICES-->

                          <input id="7" type="checkbox" name="download[]" value="7"><label>7</label><br>
                          <input id="8" type="checkbox" name="download[]" value="8"><label>8</label><br>
                          <span class="help-inline"></span> 
                     </div>
                    </div>
```

and below here is the email that they will receive with the download link. from here im able to echo the device they want to download but not able to provide them the link.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<b><font size="4"> Download Link</font></b><BR><BR>

<p>Dear <?php echo $name ?>,</p>
<p>Thank you for signing up at <a href="http://localhost/test/" target="_blank">   test.com</a>.<br> 
<p>Following is the link to download the device pdf that you have selected.</p><br> 
<?php   

echo $checkBox;
?>
```

Comment: not sure what you are having trouble with

Comment: im unable to echo download link based on checkbox they tick..

Answer (score 0):

Your checkboxes have values (1,2,3), right? The next step would be to relate these values to your pdf file names, in order to build the anchor later on. In order to do that, you would set up an array for the checkbox value to pdf file relation. Just for example, if checkbox `1` is selected, then the pdf name is `one.pdf`.

```
// checkbox value to pdf filenames array
$pdf_filenames = array(
    '1' => 'one.pdf',
    '2' => 'two.pdf'
);

// $selected is the value of the selected checkbox
// fetch it from $_POST['download']

$pdf_filename = $pdf_filenames[$selected];

// build anchor template for the email   
$link_template = '<a src="http://the.website/downloads/%s">Download %s</a>';

// insert the values via sprintf (maybe the second one is $selected, dunno)
$link = sprintf($link_template, $pdf_filename, $pdf_filename);

// for usage in the email template
echo $link; 

// result: <a src="http://the.website/downloads/one.pdf">Download one.pdf</a>
```

I assumed that the first part of the download link is static and only the filename changes.

---

Question from Comment:

> may i know why got 2 $pdf_filename?

The $link_template is a string. It is prepared for usage with sprintf().
`%` marks a placeholder and `s` means that the argument is treated as and presented as a string, when formatted by sprintf.  That's why there are to placeholders for strings: the two `%s`.

Now, when sprintf() is called, the first parameter is the template string.
The next two paremeters are the variables containing the values, which should be inserted for the %s placeholders.

The first placeholder is inside the src tag. It's obviously the filename.
The second placeholder might be the filename or the value of the checkbox or a modified filename - it depends, on what you want to show as the anchor / link content.
For instance, you could truncate the file extension and just print `one` as the link.

Comment: may i know why got 2 $pdf_filename?

Comment: btw im having  unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)  error at $pdf_filenames

Comment: Sry, i missed to add `array` in front of the braces. It's `$pdf_filenames = array(`. I will append my answer, in order to answer your question regarding the 2 $pdf_filenames in the sprintf.